# Can't login into paypal developer site

Tags: paypal

I can't login using my paypal developer account since paypal changed it. I forgot my password and when I click problem logging in, I am redirected to paypal.com and I am being treated as a paypal user and not developer and it tells me that my mail doesn't exist. I can't even create a new developer account. I can still login using one of the test accounts and when I am logged it, it shows up in the page logged as "mymail@site.com" which is my email I used for creating the developer account which I currently don't remember its password and if I opened developer.paypal.com it shows that I am not logged it, although in the sandbox it says am logged in. I am a non US developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of last week you'll need to login to the PayPal Developer Portal at https://developer.paypal.com/ using a live PayPal account. This can be your own - if you're the sole developer - or the live transacting PayPal account.

Once you're logged in with this account, you'll be able to import your old test accounts using your old developer log-in.

Comment: I have the same issue, I've tried to import the test accounts with no success.

Comment: How come if I used live paypal account I'll be able to retrieve the test accounts. When I created the developer account I used my personal email and then I created the 2 test accounts one personal and another business and I didn't enter at any step the live paypal account so how they are linked together?

Comment: I tried to login with the live account and when clicked "Import Data" it asked me to enter the sandbox email and password. Sandbox credentials are supposed to be my developer account or the test account credientails? If am supposed to enter my developer account email and password then I don't remember the password and I don't know how to retrieve it and if it means the test account then the email validator keeps saying enter valid email for the email I enter which looks like this xxxxxx_1361363321_biz@xxxx.net.

Comment: For importing, it means the old developer account.  If you don't know the email/password, I suggest creating new sandbox accounts.  But you can also try accessing the old developer via https://developer.sandbox.paypal.com/ and reset its password.

Comment: The url https://developer.sandbox.paypal.com/ is not available, I do know the email but I don't remember the password and I can't create a new account because in the sign up form it says: Currently, this is only available to U.S. businesses. As I mentioned am not a US developer.

Comment: Ah you're right, the old sandbox is no longer available.

Well, you should be able to log in with any live PayPal account.  If the developer.paypal.com interface doesn't let you create one because you aren't in the US, use www.paypal.com to create your account.   Then sign in with it at developer.paypal.com

Comment: Do we need to create a account on live paypal site for using the existing sandbox account?

Comment: To manage it via developer.paypal.com , yes

To use it via the PayPal APIs , no